# Convergence of random sum of random variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

Consider a family of real-valued random variables $\{X_n(t)\}$, $n \in \{0,1, 2, \cdots\}$ and $t \in [0,1]$. Suppose the finite dimensional distributions of $\{X_n(t)\}$ converge to $\{\overline{X}_n\}$ as $t \rightarrow 0$. Also, we have $T(t) \rightarrow \overline{T}$ in distribution as $t \rightarrow 0$. $T(t)$ and $\overline{T}$ are stopping times. Then is the following result true: $$\sum_{n=1}^{T_t} X_n(t) \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\overline{T}} \overline{X}_n  $$ in distribution as $t \rightarrow 0$. The sequences involved are not i.i.d.

Comment: I would expect the answer to be no. For instance $X_nY_n $ need not converge in distribution to $XY $ if $X_n \to X $ and $Y_n \to Y $.